# Decimal value displays as 0.00

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

I am saving a salary value in my project (using EF Code first) In my model I have -

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
[Display(Name = "Salary")]
public Decimal Salary { get; set; }
```

And when I look in my database it appears to be saved correctly. I can see the value as 50000.00 and the column is Salary (decimal(18,2), not null)

However in my view when I try to display this value it is showing as 0.00

The code in the view is

```
<tr>
    <td>Salary</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Salary)</td>
</tr>
```

Any idea why it's displaying 0.00 instead of 50000.00?

Comment: Can you post your controller code? (or the bits showing how you retrieve the entity from the database and your action for the view)

Comment: What happens if you change your `DataFormatString` to `0:0.00##`?

Comment: Jaimal - Thanks, I has a spelling mistake in the conmtroller, correcting it has solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
```

Also confirm you have an actual value in controller either through a test or print without format to the screen, i.e. `@Model.Salary`

Comment: @MartinMcMahon have you confirmed there is a value there?  I'd updated answer as you were typing that